# What is the significance of having high pgfree/s on a linux system?

Tags: linux, performance, garbage-collection, system

I am seeing high pgfree/s values in sar for an application. Generally is this an issue I should be concerned about? If so, what is generally the cause, spending time lots of time in GC?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your machine is doing as to whether it's an issue.  pgfree/s is the number of pages the kernel is putting on the free list per second.  The free list is where the kernel tracks unallocated memory.  So if you're doing a lot of memory allocation/deallocation (like by creating and destroying a lot of processes), then it should be fine.  More info about memory and the free list can be found [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/spt2/chapter/ch04.html).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could find about **sar** that may shed some light on your question is from [Redhat](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-9-Manual/admin-primer/s1-resource-rhlspec.html). However I can not see anything there that could be related to garbage collection.